# Update parent version in a maven project's module

Tags: java, maven, teamcity, pom.xml

I've a strange scenario where I have a project "Y" and it has a module "X" and some other modules as well.

X is part of a project Y however it is not linked as a module of that project. Because of that, each time a newer version of Y is released someone needs to manually update the parent version in X.

I need to update the Y project in such a way that:
a)each time the Y project is released, the parent project version in X should be automatically updated by TeamCity (in a similar way as for other modules)

b)X must not be a part of Y distribution

c)Once deployed in TeamCity, it should not run tests from X (they should be run with Integration tests and Release builds)

Answer (score 17):

## versions:update-parent

If you open a terminal at the root of your project `X`, you can use `versions:update-parent` to update its parent version to the `latest`:

```
$ mvn versions:update-parent -DallowSnapshots=true
```

You can execute this command from TeamCity and then commit the changes to the pom. This can certainly be triggered when `Y` is built, you could even provide the version (it must be a `list` or a `range`):

```
$ mvn versions:update-parent -DparentVersion=[1.0.0,1.0.1]    //or [1.0.0,1.5.0)
```

## Documentation

See [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)'s documentation, especially:

- #### versions:update-parent

> updates the parent section of a project so that it references the
>   newest available version. For example, if you use a corporate root
>   POM, this goal can be helpful if you need to ensure you are using the
>   latest version of the corporate root POM.

- #### versions:set

> can be used to set the project version from the command line.

- #### versions:commit

> removes the pom.xml.versionsBackup

- #### versions:update-child-modules

> updates the parent section of the child modules of a project so the
>   version matches the version of the current project. For example, if
>   you have an aggregator pom that is also the parent for the projects
>   that it aggregates and the children and parent versions get out of
>   sync, this mojo can help fix the versions of the child modules. (Note
>   you may need to invoke Maven with the -N option in order to run this
>   goal if your project is broken so badly that it cannot build because
>   of the version mis-match).

Comment: Thanks Alex for the reply.As I'm quite new to Maven and want to embed this within pom. xml. I wanted to know whether there is any pom.xml equivalent to the command line argument "mvn versions:update-parent -DallowSnapshots=true"?

And how can I refer the updated parent version inside the parent tag?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This is the maven way do to it, you need to execute this maven command to update the pom automatically

Comment: Okay.....Just wanted to tell that X is a part of the Project Y but not added as a module to the project Y.In that case, how would I verify whether the X module is taking the updated version of Y?
Also, I've seen that executing the command only take the most updated version. What if I want my parent to point to an older version?

Comment: Then, this "mvn versions:update-parent -DparentVersion=[1.0.0,1.0.1]"  should allow you to set a range of version to upgrade to

Comment: How do I test the scenario that whether the X module is taking the updated version of Y as I couldn't see the module X  getting created in the M2 repo?

Comment: update Y, commit it, release Y. Go to X, type "versions:update-parent", it's parent gets updated, commit the pom, release X. These steps can all be done from TeamCity too.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks.The solution works perfectly if I run the "mvn versions:update-parent" However, instead of using the command line option,if I use the "version plugin" in the pom.xml of the "X" module and try to build it, then it doesn't take the updated version of Parent. I guess it'll be better if you can give me a pom entry which will do the same thing as "version:update:parent"

Comment: Can this command be reliably used to update a project version back to SNAPSHOT after releasing a milestone?

Comment: Is there any way to update the parent version to a specific version? not a range!

Comment: I found you can put just one thing in the range [version]