# How to update the parent version in a pom file?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Maven v3.0.5

I have a pom.xml file that has a parent stanza, like this

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.company.artifacts.root</groupId>
  <artifactId>td-root</artifactId>
  <relativePath>./..</relativePath>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

How do I update the version to say 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT so the resulting pom.xml file has this?

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.company.artifacts.root</groupId>
  <artifactId>td-root</artifactId>
  <relativePath>./..</relativePath>
  <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

I read [Update parent version in a maven project's module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449275/update-parent-version-in-a-maven-projects-module) and of course [Maven versions:update-parent](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/update-parent.html) page, and have tried the following

```
$ mvn versions:update-parent -DparentVersion=[1.0.1-SNAPSHOT] -DallowSnapshots=true
```

to no avail.

Comment: You should check the [goals docs](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-parent-mojo.html) and add `-DallowSnapshots=true`. Apart from that using `<relativePath>..</relativePath>` is not needed cause that is the default.

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks; +1 on the relativePath info.

Comment: The -DallowSnapshots didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Which version versions-maven-plugin do you use?

Comment: mvn versions:help shows Versions Maven Plugin 2.4